# Wix: how to create database using SqlScript

Tags: database, wix

I need to create a simple database named MyDB by using Wix by using SqlString. Below is my code snippet. For the line (SQL="CREATE DATABASE MyDB"), may i know is this correct and will it create 'MyDB' database? I've set the User and Server attribute correctly. However, this allows installation but it does not create the database. Can anyone point out what is wrong or missing?

```
<sql:SqlDatabase Id='SqlDatabase' Database='master' User='SQLUser' Server='[SQLSERVER]' 
              CreateOnInstall='no' DropOnUninstall='no' ContinueOnError='yes'>

              <sql:SqlString Id="InitialCreateDB" ExecuteOnInstall="no" ContinueOnError="yes"
                          SQL="CREATE DATABASE MyDB"/>
            </sql:SqlDatabase>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The verbose log will tell you more about what's going on behind the scenes...

Comment: And the SQL Profiler will offer up more detail from the SQL Server side.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you have a script file containing SQL code to create the database.

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" 
xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension" 
xmlns:sql="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/SqlExtension">
  <Product Name='SQL app 1.0' Id='DB501C18-86C7-4D14-AEC0-86416A69ABDE' Language='1033' Codepage='1252'
     Version='1.0.0' Manufacturer='ABC Ltd.'>
            <Package Id='????????-????-????-????-????????????' Keywords='Installer' Description="SQL App 1.0 Installer"
              Comments='Comment.' Manufacturer='ABC Ltd.' InstallerVersion='100'
              Languages='1033' Compressed='yes' SummaryCodepage='1252' />
        <Media Id='1' Cabinet='Sample.cab' EmbedCab='yes' />
        <User Id="MySQLUser" Name="[SQLUSER]" Password="[SQLUSERPASSWORD]"></User>
        <Directory Id='TARGETDIR' Name='SourceDir'>
            <Directory Id='ProgramFilesFolder' Name='PFiles'>
                <Directory Id='INSTALLDIR' Name='TestSQL'>
                      <Component Id="MySqlComponent" Guid="C50999A0-02FD-42d5-9F65-7375318DD328">
                        <SqlDatabase Id="MySqlDatabase" Database="MyDatabase" Server="[SQLSERVER]" Instance="[SQLINSTANCE]"
                            CreateOnInstall="yes" DropOnUninstall="yes" User="MySQLUser" ContinueOnError="yes">
                              <SqlScript Id="CreateDatabase" ExecuteOnInstall="yes" BinaryKey="CreateTablesBin"></SqlScript>
                        </SqlDatabase>
                      </Component>
                </Directory>
             </Directory>
         </Directory>
        <Binary Id="CreateTablesBin" src="CreateDatabase.sql"></Binary>
        <Feature Id='Complete' Level='1' Description="Full" Title="Full Installation">
            <ComponentRef Id='MySqlComponent' />
        </Feature>
    </Product>
</Wix>
```

Comment: Note the nesting of the SqlDatabase element below Component in order to create the database.  Note that the Database attribute is [Formatted][1], so it can contain reference to Properties.

  [1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa368609.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Set the `CreateOnInstall` value to "yes". This will than create an instance of the database.